# How to read a file in Node JS / Express JS Project?

Tags: node.js, excel, express

In my Node JS / Express JS project, I need to get an excel project and I will be using this library **read-excel-file**.

I need to get the file path in order to continue with this code from the library documentation:

```
  const readXlsxFile = require('read-excel-file/node');
 
  // File path.
  readXlsxFile('/path/to/file').then((rows) => {
     // `rows` is an array of rows
     // each row being an array of cells.
  })
```

I don't understand about the file path, I can't get it from an `<input type='file' />` I only get the file name.
but the location of the file is on the client device not on the server so how could this workout?

Comment: Well the path to file is his location on the client side. I tested it by inserting a file path manually (from a text input).

Comment: By using a type file input, I am not able to get the full path, and this is my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CAN NOT access file on client file system from an HTTP server. You will need to send the file from client to server.

There's a lot of resource available online which can help with file upload but the gist is that file is send as a multipart-data from client to server. In Express server, `multer` module is used to access the file in `req.file` property.